# Unable to read parameter and facing problem in loading component again on changing parameter in route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular6, angular-routing

I am working on a Angular Project where I am facing problem in routing.

1. I am unable to read the parameter once it is passed through route on selecting any options in the navbar.
2. I am unable to reload the component once parameter of the route changes

My navbar code is given below

**TS FILE**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks:any;
  token: any;
  responsesportstypedata: any;
  store = [];
  matchname: any;

  constructor(  private rest : ServicesService , public router : Router ) {
    console.log(location.pathname);

    this.loadDataFromApi();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  getMatchid(val){
 this.router.navigate(['matchcenter',val]);
    }
     loadDataFromApi() {
     this.token =  localStorage.getItem('putoken');
      console.log('token == ' + this.token);
     this.rest.getSportstype().then(
      result => {
       this.responsesportstypedata = result;
       this.store = this.responsesportstypedata;


       },
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div (click)='getMatchid(item.ttypeUid)'>{{item.ttypeName})</div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

 { path: 'matchcenter' , component: MatchcenterComponent},
 { path: 'matchcenter/:matchname' , component: MatchcenterComponent}

];
```

On path http://localhost:4200/matchcenter/:matchname , I am passing **matchname** dynamically ,

it can be 
**http://localhost:4200/matchcenter/Football**
or
**http://localhost:4200/matchcenter/Cricket**

once component **MatchcenterComponent** is loaded but 
on parameter of the rout changes  component **MatchcenterComponent** dosen't reload

The following code is for MatchcenterComponent.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { ServicesService } from '../service/services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matchcenter',
  templateUrl: './matchcenter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matchcenter.component.scss']
})
export class MatchcenterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public rest : ServicesService , public router : Router , public dialog: MatDialog , public _route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    console.log('matchcenterPage');
    console.log(location.pathname);
    this.loadDataFromApi();
   }   
  ngOnInit() {

     const id = +this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('matchname');
    this.router.navigate(['/matchcenter',matchName]);
    console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++' + matchName);
      //  this.router.navigate(['matchcenter/Cricket']);
  }
}
```

NOTE : my other routes is working fine so   is working

Comment: Try Changing the order in your routes,

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'matchcenter/:matchname' , component: MatchcenterComponent}
 { path: 'matchcenter' , component: MatchcenterComponent},
];

Comment: maybe you're missing this one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez no

Comment: @JohnVelasquezthanks sir , But I have edited the Question for more clear view , so Kindly see

Comment: @KarthikRPthanks sir , But I have edited the Question for more clear view , so Kindly see

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your html file.

Second, in the `ngOnInit()` from MatchCenterComponent you are converting the parameter `'matchname'` to an integer, but since it will be Football or Cricket, it will result in a NaN.

Third, aswell in the `ngOnInit()`, you are navigating to `['/matchcenter',matchName]`, but this will return a MatchCenterComponent, so you will be in an endless loop.

Comment: thanks sir , But I have edited the Question for more clear view , so Kindly see